# How to create tableview cell that inherits from base tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to ask the question simply without further ado. I have a Base TableViewCell class designed with an XIB file.

**NIB File Name** = "BaseFile" ,**Identifier** = "baseCell" ,**class name** = BaseTableViewCell

**For Example:**

```
class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
...
}
```

I want to create multiple tableView cells with this cell.

**For example :**

```
class ATableViewCell : BaseTableViewCell {

    func configure(...) {
         label1.text  = "...."
         label2.text  = "...."
    }
}
```

And

```
class BTableViewCell : BaseTableViewCell {

    func configure(...) {
         label1.text  = "...."
         label2.text  = "...."
    }
}
```

***Problem :***

I get an error similar to this when creating the cell: "Could not cast value of ... "

***The method I tried:***

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
// REGISTER CELL
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BaseFile", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "baseCell")
        
        self.editUserFieldsTableView.delegate = self
        self.editUserFieldsTableView.dataSource = self

    }

...
...

let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "baseCell") 
as! BaseTableViewCell) as! ATableViewCell
```

***Question :***
How can I manage this situation? and Can I create the base tableview cell with generic ?

Comment: That should work. Which line gives the error, and what, exactly, is the error message? Note that you don't need to (and shouldn't) cast first to `BaseTableViewCell` and then to `ATableViewCell`. Just cast directly to `ATableViewCell`

Comment: Error :  Could not cast value of type 'BaseCell' (0x108ca6d70) to 'ATableViewCell' . @DuncanC

Comment: Looks like it's down to that two-fold casting.  You're trying to cast the parent class as the child class.  Effectively you are saying that the new cell is a `BaseTableCell`, which is fine, but then you are saying that the cell you;ve just defined as a `BaseTableCell` is an `ATableViewCell`.  That will never work.  As @DuncanC pointed out, just cast directly to `ATableViewCell`

Comment: I think you can not cast to ATC if your nib has a BaseCell inside. Also try to not force unwrapping : it show you what is possible or not.

Comment: The sooner you can ditch Interface Builder and just do this programmatically the better, IMO.